# Cannot run anything: -bash: fork: retry: No child processes

Tags: ubuntu, memory, operating-systems, process

Sometimes when I try to SSH to my server, I can't run any command because of this error:

```
-bash: fork: retry: No child processes
```

Every time I hit the error, I am unable to run any command. I have to restart server.

I searched on Google, it looks like the maximum allowed processes is reached and no more process can be start, so it shows the error.

On my way trying to find out what is the reason, I decided to restart my server, wait for a couple days, then SSH in (while I still can) and check the process list. I could see there is a lot `openssl` process.

[image]

Result of `ps -ef`: https://pastebin.com/9EsTub21

I could see there is more than 3800 process of `openssl`.

Can someone help me explain what's going on here?

My system:

```
Linux hac2-vn 4.4.0-116-generic #140-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 12 21:23:04 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your cron daemon is starting openssl every minute, and the openssl process doesn't stop.  You should reboot, stop cron as soon as possible, and search all the cron configurations for openssl.

Comment: Wow, how can you tell? I have a cronjob (run inside a docker container) but it starting a nodejs process. How is it related to openssl? I'll try disable the 1min cronjob to see what happen.

Comment: Holy moly... it's correct. I don't know how did you know what was going on, but you just helped me resolve the longest issue I ever meet (and procrastinated) for the last 1 year.  THANKS!

Comment: It was visible in your ps output.  The PPID (parent process id) of all the openssl 's was the same, it was the PID of the cron daemon.  If you feel like it, please accept my answer.